# Videogular2 issue with the default controls

Tags: angular, video

In videogular2 if I use all the default controls for a vghls video,I'm seeing few issues like play of undefined,ele of undefined.How to use all the controls for a vghls video?The default controls work for normal mp4 video.

Comment: Post your code what you tried for videogular2

Comment: Done,I'm able to add additional controls now.